# Gwt + google Maps Api Mobile Bug

Tags: gwt, google-maps-api-2, mgwt

I tested this Tutorial :
https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/MapsGettingStarted

copy and pasted it into my Project, compiled it and uploaded it to my testwebsite,
so if I try to move around the map with my Android Phone it jumps always back to the start position.

the same happen to me if I try this code:

http://lehelsipos.blogspot.de/2012/10/mgwt-using-gwt-map-widget-on-mobile.html

Answer (score 0):

OK after few Hours i found the solution -> https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/downloads/list google gwt maps 3.8.0 prerealease